# Why does Objective-C allow a semicolon at the end of a method definition?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Semicolon after the method name in Objective-C implementation file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678360/semicolon-after-the-method-name-in-objective-c-implementation-file)

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Why I add ; at the end of the function is also correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an Objective-C convenience. It's so that you can copy/paste the method signature line from your header file. It's one of those things that has been around since the NeXTStep days.

Comment: Thank you! It seems you know lots of the NEXTStep's history, great!