# I can't figure how to fix this Expected identifier or '('

Tags: ios, ibaction, iboutlet

```
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender;  {                                   Expected identifier or '('

    IBOutlet UITextField *Firstnamefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Lastnamefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *emailfield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *agefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordfield:
    IBOutlet UITextField *reenterpasswordfield;
}
```

Comment: Is this your .h or .m file? And why are the IBOutlets not @property?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender {
   UITextField *Firstnamefield;
   UITextField *Lastnamefield;
   UITextField *emailfield;
   UITextField *agefield;
   UITextField *passwordfield;
   UITextField *reenterpasswordfield;
}
```

There a couple of problems. For one, you can not use the IBOutlet qualifier outside of an interface declaration. And `passwordfield` has a colon after it that should be a semicolon.

In case this is the point of confusion, if you were creating the interface declaration for this IBAction, it would look like this:

```
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender;
```

Other than that, the only other thing that could be causing this is if you are trying to place the entire IBAction inside the header file.

Comment: no I need the semi colon I don't know whats wrong it still says expected identifier '('

Comment: A semicolon is actually allowed in the method definition, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976975/why-does-objective-c-allow-a-semicolon-at-the-end-of-a-method-definition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you put an IBAction at the wrong place in the .h file.
It should be *after* the definition of the instance variables, for example:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *Firstnamefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Lastnamefield; 
    // ...
}
- (IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: @user2671626: What does not work? Do you get a compiler error?