# semicolons at end of method implementations

Tags: objective-c

Are these two identical? Why would you use one over the other?

`-(void)someMethod; { stuff }`

vs.

`-(void)someMethod { stuff }`

Comment: to the first two that answered: it is in fact valid syntax and the compiler and runtime do not complain. i am reading a book on programming and all the examples do the implementation with the semicolon, which i've never seen before. hence the question; i know it is odd.

Comment: I stand corrected. It sure looks wrong, but if it works, it works. I do not know enough about objective-c to say whether it is correct syntax. It is not a widely used language, so I guess a lot of it is down to what the compiler will actually accept.

Comment: It certainly works, but I think this is a historical artifact.  It's not encouraged by Apple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Semicolon after the method name in Objective-C implementation file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678360/semicolon-after-the-method-name-in-objective-c-implementation-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was from Josh Caswell:

It's syntactically valid; a weird artifact in the language from the NeXT days.

Answer (score 1):

The first one just looks wrong. Normally in your .h file you would have something like:

```
-(void)someMethod;
```

And in the .m file you would have:

```
-(void)someMethod { stuff }
```

Perhaps the first one came about as the result of some cut and paste operation, and the compiler just accepted it.

Comment: see comment i added to my question

Answer (score 0):

`-(void)someMethod;` is declaration of the method and `-(void)someMethod { stuff }` is its implementation.

Declaration of methods should be written in headers files (ex. `MyClass.h`) if you want them to be visible outside of class and implementations should be written in implementationes fils (ex. `MyClass.m`).

And I don't think that `-(void)someMethod; { stuff }` is possible.

Comment: see comment i added to my question

Comment: It's syntactically valid; a weird artifact in the language from the NeXT days.