# Should we remove ; at the end of the implementation in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Semicolon after the method name in Objective-C implementation file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678360/semicolon-after-the-method-name-in-objective-c-implementation-file)

I noticed that both

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
{

}
```

and

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

}
```

works.

Using ; is kind of awkward though. Why having ; works is beyond me. Wouldn't work in C++

The thing is `something;` should be equivalent with `something{};` hence `something ;{}` should be equivalent with `something {};{}` which is just wrong.

For example if(true) a=b; is the same with if(true){a=b};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiler ignores the semicolon, this happens only with function names.This happens when people try to copy the function name from .h(interface) to .m(implementation)file.I also observed the same while working with objective c.

Answer (score 2):

As Brad Larson says in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678360/semicolon-after-the-method-name-in-objective-c-implementation-file/5678458#5678458):

> Yes, it is acceptable syntax to do this.
>
> In fact, I always do this in my implementations, because it then is
>   trivial to copy and paste a method definition from interface to
>   implementation and vice versa without having to remember where you
>   are. It helps that I use aligned brackets on separate lines, as well.

Likewise, [Yuji states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678360/semicolon-after-the-method-name-in-objective-c-implementation-file/5678388#5678388):

> Grammatically it is OK to put a semicolon there. It serves no purpose,
>   and it is discouraged to do that. Some compilers give warnings about
>   this extra semicolon.

C/C++/Java treats a ; as end of statement, so whenever compiler finds it treats it as end of line.

EDIT:

`if(true) a=b;` is the same with `if(true){a=b};`

These can not be compared with above. `a=b` is an expression which has to be terminated by a semi-colon. Therefore, `if(true) a=b;` is Correct. `if(true){a=b;}` is correct. But `if(true) {a=b};` is not, { and } makes a block which contains an un-terminiated expression, making a semantic error, so compiler says ERROR.

Comment: No, this is wrong, even if you add ; and then write {}, function works!

Comment: for is different from function!

Comment: ahaa thnks for -1, by reason please...

Comment: The thing is something; should be equivalent with something{}; hence something ;{} should be equivalent with something {};{} which is just wrong.

Comment: There are few more thing we find in xcode, objective-c, cocoa interesting... this is not just one.

Comment: If you quote the words of others, you need to be very clear with attribution. I've edited your answer to make this more explicit, but please be sure to do this yourself in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
{

}
```

and

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{

}
```

both have same meaning.

Actually compiler ignores `;` if present after function

Even if you write

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

}
```

as

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
{

}
```

it works!