# Expected identifier or '(' for void dealloc

Tags: xcode, identifier, dealloc

I am getting a "expected identifier or'(' message in Xcode. This comes after (void)dealloc;
I am not sure how to fix this or why it is coming up. If someone could tell me how to fix this, I would appreciate it. I am basic at this, so I would appreciate a step by step solution. Thanks a lot! My code:

```
   - (void)dealloc;
{
    [testView release];
    [lblMsg release];
    [super dealloc];
    [scroll release];
    [pager release];
    [viewControllers release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**Update:** Thank you all for your outstanding help. I have resolved the issue by using a completely different method to reach my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the semicolon after

```
- (void) dealloc
```

in your .m file.

You only need the semicolon after that dealloc method declaration in your .h file.

Comment: Thanks. Let me clarify. I have this code in my .h not my .m because if I put it in the .m I get a warning about the ARC or something. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: See, all I really want to do is create screens based off page control. If you know of a good tutorial (especially through Storyboard) I would appreciate it.

Comment: "`release`" and "`retain`" only work if ARC is turned off. Since you have ARC turned on, you shouldn't be be doing any releases at all (and you can get rid of your "`dealloc`" method entirely). Or, if you're strictly following a tutorial you found, turn ARC off and then everything should compile just as the tutorial you're looking at has it. In general, you should use ARC though. Less debugging for you in the long run.

Comment: So I should just get rid of dealloc and continue with the tutorial? Thanks a lot Michael. Helped out!

Comment: @user2329093: "I have this code in my .h not my .m" You cannot put code (or any *definitions*) in the header file for a reason. Header files are for other files to import. Something (a function or variable or Objective-C class) cannot be *defined* (i.e. implemented) more than once in the same program. So you cannot put them in the header file. You can only put *declarations* in the header file.

Comment: @user2329093: You're also calling `[super dealloc]` twice, which isn't a good thing.

Comment: The semicolon is not the problem here, and a semicolon after a method name is allowed - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678458/1144632

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you have [super ...] twice. Most of the effective sample code I have seen puts (leaves) this first and only once. You can use // before a line or multiple lines to see if the error goes away and if it will run without that (possibly unnecessary) code.  I have found that the [... release] lines are sometimes allowed and often not allowed as stated earlier. Again,  // is for commenting out a line of code, but can also be "restored" by simply deleting the //.